# Crazy British Femizon TV show/movie - 1970s

Tags: story-identification, tv

Saw this nutty movie (or series) on late-late-night television in LA in the '70s - fell asleep before the end. Begins on a planet populated by British amazons; one (or maybe two) flee in a space ship & land on contemporary Earth. Amazons send police to fetch them back & they are amazed to find a planet dominated by men.  All the props, sets & equipment seem to have been used on 'Space: 1999'.

Comment: Does the term femizon mean something within the show? Typically, Amazons are women by definition.

Comment: Adamant - I got the term 'femizon' from 1970s Marvel comics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sounds like "Star Maidens". Made in the 1970's. It was a British - German co production and the Wikipedia page for it notes that many props and sets from Space 1999 we reused for this show. The format was a type of battle of the sexes. You can read a detailed description of the show here...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Maidens

additionally there are episodes to watch on Youtube. This is the link to the first episode.

Comment: Skyjack - This is it - I forgot Judy Geeson was in it. Thanks!